# Last write time logic in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to write a simple logic to trigger an event in the following condition:

- If a file is present in a folder and the last modified date in the other folder is greater than 1 hour(file has not been modified for more than 1 hour/ minutes etc.), then trigger event.

I have wrote the following login in powershell, but I'm not sure its what I want.

```
if ((Test-Path D:\Projects\test\*) -and (Get-ChildItem D:\Projects | Where{($_).LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)})) {
    $value = $TRUE
    (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)
    ($_).LastWriteTime
    Write-Host "pass"
    Write-Host $value
}
else {
    $value = $FALSE
    Write-Host "fail"
    Write-Host $value
}
```

Is something missing in the logic or I am taking a wrong path?

**Note**: There are many  files in the other folder where we need to check the last modified date. We need to check the last modified date of the latest file.

Comment: Your loop works fine. Insert the trigger action in your `if loop` and your job is done.

Comment: Thanks @VivekKumar but there is one more condition I forgot to mention. There are a lot of files in the folder (for last modified date) and I need to compare only the latest file. I think I am missing on the sorting part.

Comment: That's easy. Use the `select-object` cmdlet like this.
`(Get-ChildItem D:\Projects | Where{($_).LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)} | select-object -First 1)`.
Given that the files are sorted in descending order according to `LastWriteTime` then your latest file will be selected.

Comment: I am getting "true" every time even after 2-3 minutes after the file is created. it is not flowing to false.

Comment: Have you checked if your file created is dynamic? Like a file is getting created as the script is running. In that case it will again be true. Else I don't see any flaw. You can test this `(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-2) -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)`. This will always return false.

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with your other requirement:

```
$Test = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)
$Files = Get-ChildItem D:\Projects |
  Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $Test } |
  Select-Object -First 1

If ((Test-Path D:\Projects\test\*) -and $Files)
{
    $value = $TRUE
    $Test
    $Files.LastWriteTime
    Write-Host "pass"
    Write-Host $value
}
Else
{
    $value = $FALSE
    Write-Host "fail"
    Write-Host $value
}
```